# Setting SQL Trigger to Count Foreign Column

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

So I just found about about triggers, and I'm intrigued.

How would I go about setting table `b.y` to the count of all of the entries in table `a.x` where `a.x = c`?

What about setting table `b.y` to the sum of all of the entries where `a.x = c`?

Comment: sounds like a join and a sum...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't have a computed column using aggregation functions, but you can have it reference a user defined function.

Comment: you should create a scalar function (user defined function) to count any field you want. then you should just use it in your calculated column.